# How to set Timezone in request.security()?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

**I want to check the bar external call in my time zone and not in the boring exchange time zone.**

The function `request.security()` does not allow entering a `Timezone` such as `"GMT-3"` or other.

```
request.security(syminfo.tickerid, timeframe.period, expression, gaps, lookahead, ignore_invalid_symbol, currency)
```

I need to insert a `timezone("GMT-3")` inside `request.security()`, but I can't.

I've already tried `conditioning ( ? )` in `request.security()` to a `time()` checker:

Example: (compact):

```
tz = time(timeframe.period, syminfo.session, "GMT-3")
r = (time == tz) ? request.security() : na
```

`Return: none.`

The `Runtime` `not call` `request.security()` or `continues` presents `same timezone of exchange.`

Why did `TradingView` forgot adding a `Timezone` in the `request.security()` function?

`TradingView` should `upgrade` `request.security()` by inserting the `Timezone` function at the time I want to check the closing of the bar in my time zone.

**Does anyone know how to insert a Timezone inside request.security() ?**

Image Example: In My Screen.

[image]

The image represents my screen.
The `yellow line` represents the `closing value of bar "1D"` in `request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "1D", close[1]) with gaps off.`

Note that `request.security()` changes the line only when `closing the "1D" daily bar.`

In `request.security()` the `daily bar "1D"` `closes` in the `exchange` `time zone` `"GMT+8"`.
So for my view in my `timezone` it shows that it `closes at 13:00` because I am `"GMT-3"`.

If `request.security()` was `set to "GMT-3"` then my chart should `close the "1D" bar at 00:00 ("GMT-3")`. You should be the solution!

**Does anyone know how to insert a Timezone inside request.security() ?**

Comment: Request whatever you need to request with the `security()` and then handle the timezone yourself?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a timezone parameter in the request.security function
Just change your chart timezone to the one you want manually and.... it will do the job :)

Kind regards
Dave

Comment: Not.
My chart is set to GMT-3 and yet request.security() continues to close the daily bar ("1D") in the exchange's timezone which is GMT+8.
On my request.security() chart it closes the day at 13:00 while it should close at 00:00 if it had a GMT-3 timezone.
Still the same problem!

Comment: Got it, you're correct
I believe @vitruvius gave you the answer in the comment then
Use the time function with the timezone you want and when it hour(time) == 00 and minute(time) == 00, you can set with some pine code your custom day change

Comment: I updated the post with more details and an image to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with pivot points, and included "gaps = barmerge.gaps_off, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on" after "syminfo.tickerid, "1D", close[1]". It worked for me